# How to convert as single row this data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID          Name    Age   Result
1           Karthi  21    11.05
1           Karthi  21    25.00
2           Raja    23    15.00
2           Raja    23    17.00
```

I need result in

```
ID Name   Age  Result  Result1
1  Karthi 21   11.05    25.00
2  Raja   23   15.00    17.00
```

like that ....

Comment: You can do this with group by name and a sum() function for the result.

Comment: What RDBMS?  You could assign a row_number to each ID and then pivot on the row number.  or perform a self join.  Will there always only be 2 results or could it be n?  Does the smaller of the results always come first in the results or how do you determine which goes to result vs result1?

Comment: i don't need sum of result ...i just show in single row ...

Comment: There are hundreds of questions like this already. Did you really not find anything on a search?

Comment: WHERE'S YOUR SQL SERVER TAG????

Comment: Have you even tried anything?  Have you Googled your question?  There are tons of example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the data in table named myTable then the following query will do the trick:

```
--The low values per ID
select id, Name, age , max(Result) as Result1
into #tmp1 from myTable
GROUP BY id,Name,Age

--The high values per ID
select id, Name, Age, min(Result) as Result
into #tmp2 from myTable
GROUP BY id,Name,Age

--Both values on the same line
select distinct t1.id, t1.Name, t1.age, t1.Result1, t2.Result
from #tmp1 t1
join #tmp2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

It will work ONLY for two lines per ID.

Comment: In case id have 3 or 2 or 1 like wise the count changing how to do that..

Comment: There is a solution also for 3 lines per ID like that:

--The low values per ID
select id, Name, age , max(Result) as Result1
into #tmp1 from myTable
GROUP BY id,Name,Age

--The high values per ID
select id, Name, Age, min(Result) as Result
into #tmp2 from myTable
GROUP BY id,Name,Age

--Both values on the same line
select distinct t1.id, t1.Name, t1.age, t1.Result1, t2.Result , t3.Result
from #tmp1 t1
join #tmp2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
left join myTable t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t1.Result1 <> t3.Result and t2.Result <> t3.Result

Comment: KARTHIKEYAN P  can you please accept my answer?
 [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)